# Replacing header in Flexviewer

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

Will the index.html swf need to be re-compiled in order to embed the flexviewer app in between a html header and footer wrapper?  Or it this perhaps handled in the HeaderControllerWidget.mxml?

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS Flex API are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

No, it doesn't have to be re-compiled.

No, it's not handled in HeaderController.

Editing the HTML file is a good idea (like Brad mentioned in his answer).  We showed an example of that at the Esri Developer Summit a few months ago.  Just take care to edit both default.htm and index.html (or know which one your web server defaults to).

Comment: thanks Bjorn, that's where I got the idea from. Great trick!

Comment: Glad you like it.   So, does this answer your question(s) or are there something you're still unclear about?  In general, if you're happy with someone's answer it's good practice to award them by marking their answer as the "accepted answer" :)

Answer (score 2):

I just modify the default.htm to add my content to the first map page